# How to print a particular column from an Avro file using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, avro

I have a following code which prints all the values from the avro file. However, I want to print a specific column 
For example:

```
{'key1': value1 , 'key2': value2}
```

I want to print all values of 'key1' present in the avro.

Here is my code

```
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader
from avro.io import DatumReader
reader = DataFileReader(open("abc.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for user in reader:
    print(user)

reader.close()
```

I am new to Avro and big data stuff

Edit:

Here is the corrected code. Thanks to @Rithin

```
for user in reader:
print(user['key1'])
```

This will return all the values corresponding to 'key1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.0/gettingstartedpython.html):

> The DataFileReader is an iterator that returns dicts corresponding to the serialized items.

Since it just returns a list of dictionaries, you can access them using `row['key']`.

Combining this with list comprehension, will result all values for all rows.

Example:

```py
all_values = [row['key1'] for row in list(reader)]
print(all_values)
```

```
[value1]
```

---

To save this resulting list to `json`, you can:

```py
import json

result = {'key1':all_values}

with open('output.json', 'w') as json_file:
  json.dump(result, json_file)
```

You can read more about saving to json [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/json).

---

To save this resulting list to `csv`, you can:

```py
import csv

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
  writer.writerows(all_values)
```

You can read more about working with csv files [here](https://realpython.com/python-csv/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can I also dump this output into a JSON or CSV format ??

Comment: @ChiragSharma, updated the answer with examples of writing to csv+json.